# How can one determine vector size at run time?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, std

At run time, can one determine the size of a `vector`?

For example

input :  25  // which shows vector size

```
  code :
        int N ;
        cin << N ;
        vector <int> data[N];
```

Comment: Are you looking for [std::vector::size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/size/)?

Comment: At run time, you cannot create a vector with size N ( unknown at compile time ) .

Comment: @fatai you probably meant 'array', not `std::vector`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, If you can create a vector without using push_back, Show me

Comment: @fatai `std::vector<int> data(N)` constructor does it.

Answer (score 13):

Two methods that might interest you:

- [`std::vector<T>::size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/size/) will return the number of elements in you vector.
- [`std::vector<T>::capacity`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/capacity/) will return the number of elements the vector has allocated memory for.

**Example snippet**

```
  std::vector<int> v;

  for (int i =0; i < 25; ++i)
    v.push_back (i);

  v.reserve (100); 

  std::cerr << "Elements: " << v.size     () << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "Capacity: " << v.capacity () << std::endl;
```

output

```
Elements: 25
Capacity: 100
```

---

I'm guessing that your example snippet in the original post contains at least one typo, you don't declare a `std::vector<int>` with `N` elements by writing the below.

What you wrote would be that data is a array of `vector<int>` of size `N`, and it would compile if N was known at compile time (or if a variable length array extension was present in your compiler).

```
vector<int> data[N];
```

---

To create a `vector` and make it insert `N` elements right from the start:

```
std::vector<int> data (N);
```

Answer (score 9):

You are using `vector` in a (probably) wrong way... that way you are defining a C-style array of N vectors (by the way, that syntax is not standard, since N would need to be known at compile time), while you probably want to define a `vector` containing `N` elements, which is done this way:

```
vector<int> data(N);
```

(which calls the one-parameter constructor of `vector`, that constructs a default-initialized array `N` elements long)

To get its size at runtime<sup>1</sup> you just have to call its method `size()`:

```
cout<<"The vector contains "<<data.size()<<" elements.\n"
```

---

1. Actually it would not even make sense to ask its size at compile-time, since `vector`'s size (intended as number of elements stored in it) is only defined at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there:

use

```
vector <int> data(N);
```

instead of

```
vector <int> data[N];
```

If you need to set all elements of your vector to a value other than zero, say, `-1`, use `vector <int> data(N, -1);`

Answer (score 2):

[Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214671/matteo-italia) is right. Just to add to his answer. You do not necessarily need to define the vector size at run time. I am assuming you are using c++.

You can just write

```
vector<int> data;
```

and then every time you want to element to the end of the vector just do

```
data.push_back(<some integer>)
```

Its not like array where you need to give them a size before using. Vectors can dynamically grow and shrink. So, you do not need to care about memory allocation. It is handled by the compiler and the `vector` class at runtime.